Python refresh error in an Excel wrkbk that has formulas with Named Ranges
I'm currently using this script to refresh an Excel workbook from python. The script works well with the exception that the formulas that have Named Ranges in them don't fully calculate and are left in an error state that reads "#NAME?".
How can I clean up this issue?
def refresh_formulas_in_excel(file_path):
    excel = win32.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
    #excel.Visible = True
    workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(file_path)
    excel.CalculateFullRebuild()  # Force full recalculation
    workbook.Save()
    workbook.Close()
    excel.Quit()

# Call before opening the workbook
refresh_formulas_in_excel(TodayFullPath)

I tried running the script with exce.Visible = True, maybe that would help but it didnt make a difference.
